# Embeddings imply isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, model-theory

Suppose you have two structures $X,Y$ over the same signature $\sigma$. If you have embeddings $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$, does this imply the existence of an isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Not in general. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/204/6085).

Comment: And [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/1058/6085).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple counterexample from $L=\{<\}$: Let $X=(0,1)$ and $Y=(0,1)\cup(1,2).$ $X$ embeds in $Y$ by inclusion, and $Y$ embeds in $X$ by just shrinking $Y$ down and putting it inside $X.$ Yet these are not isomorphic (for instance, $Y$ does not have the least upper bound property).